# How to get the value of an object type parameter into any (string ,Integer...etc ) variable?

Tags: java, string, object, generics

```java
class Fist {
    public Object age;

    public Fist(Object age)
    {

        this.age = age;
    }

    public Object getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "First{" +
                "age=" + age +
                '}';
    }

}


public class abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fist f = new Fist("44");
        String  a =(String)f.getAge();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

It is showing error java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Object.

I want that the value should get stored in string type variable a.

Comment: Did you accidentally import an `Object` class that is not `java.lang.Object`? Otherwise `java.lang.String cannot be converted to Object` does not make much sense, because `java.lang.String` extends `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: I suspect you've declared your own class called Object. I'd strongly recommend avoiding that.